# Using AJAX to do a set of sequential tasks on PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue with the inherent asynchronous-ness of AJAX with what I'm trying to accomplish...

Using a file upload form, I'm trying to send a set of data to my LAMP server which then loops through each subset of the data and generates a PDF for each subset. This takes a good 2 minutes or so to process all of the PDFs since there are so many (like 100) being generated for each subset of data.

I am hoping to use JavaScript/jQuery to segment the data into subsets that I will post to the server one at a time, and as each PDF is generated, get a response from the server and increment a progress bar, then send the next request.

How would you accomplish this in a loop? What's below doesn't work because jQuery doesn't care about the state of the server and sends all requests asynchronously.

```
var i = 0;
$.each(data_stuff, function(key, value) {
    $.post( window.location.href, { 
        stuff: key,
        data: value
    }).done(function( data ) {
        if (data == 1) {
            $('div#counter').text(i);
        }
    });                         
    $i++;
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend using `Promise`s. The following link is a good introduction: https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies (And it's not just for dummies!) In particular, check out the Chaining Promises section.

Comment: So which way are you trying to do. Do something after ALL ajax have finished, or, one ajax starts after another has finished?

Comment: one approach is to send all the data at once and have server side script update progress in session variable....then set up another long polling ajax call to monitor progress from that session variable

Comment: @A.Lau I'm trying to do one AJAX call after another, waiting for the previous one to finish before calling the next. And setting jQuery to synchronous mode just freezes the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into promises and the polling solution.

Comment: Alternative is a recursive function to make requests.... recursively call the function inside done callback as long as there is data left in array

Comment: The other thing is, your `$i++` isn't inside the done function. Meaning it'll just increment the i immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `data_stuff` is an Object, you can try this:

```
var i = 0;

// We need an array (not object) to loop trough all the posts. 
// This saves all keys that are in the object:
var keys = Object.keys(data_stuff);

function postNext() {

    // For every POST request, we want to get the key and the value:
    var key = keys[i];
    var value = data_stuff[key];

    $.post( window.location.href, { 
        stuff: key,
        data: value
    }).done(function( data ) {
        if (data == 1) {
            $('div#counter').text(i);
        }

        // Increment i for the next post
        i++;

        // If it's the last post, run postsDone
        if(i == keys.length) {
            postsDone();
        }
        // Else, run the function again:
        else {
            postNext();
        }
    });
});

postNext();

function postsDone() {
    // All data was posted
}
```

This will only post the next bit of `data_stuff` after the previous `$.post` was done.